Python regex inconsistent match for the same expression for using `search` and `findall`
Why does re have inconsistent match for the same expression for using search and findall.
import re
msg = 'data from 192.168.10.255 and 10.10.10.10'
ipregex_d = re.compile('((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])')
op = ipregex_d.search(msg)
print (op)

op = ipregex_d.findall(msg)
print (op)

Output
<re.Match object; span=(10, 24), match='192.168.10.255'> # First hit on the search is properly matched 
[('10.', '10', '255'), ('10.', '10', '10')] # IPs are not properly matched 


You only have three capturing groups (some of them being repeated), so you necessarily get three elements in the result of .findall() - the second and subsequent matches of the repeated groups overwrote the previous one.  You generally can't usefully apply a repeat count to a capturing group - what you want is something like (pat)\.(pat)\.(pat)\.(pat).  You can write that as r"\.".join(["(pat)"] * 4) to avoid having to write out the lengthy number pattern four times.

The behaviour of findall() is dependent on the number of capturing groups in the regex. To make findall() return a list of each full match then you must turn all your groups into non-capturing groups. That is, whenever you start a group with ( start it with (?: instead. eg.
# I've simplified the regex so you can see the difference
old = r'(?(?[0-9]\.){3})(?[0-9])'
new = r'(?:(?:[0-9]\.){3})(?:[0-9])'

assert re.findall(new, '0.0.0.0 and 1.2.3.4') == ['0.0.0.0', '1.2.3.4']

